# I have 1 memory leak that I cannot free

Tags: c++, c

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
    #include < stdio.h >
    #include < stdlib.h >
    #include < string.h >
    #include < crtdbg.h >
    #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

    enum {
        RUNNING = 1
    };

    struct Point {
        int x, y;
    };

    struct Line {
        Point start;
        Point end;
    };

    struct GraphicElement {
        enum {
            SIZE = 256
        };
        unsigned int numLines; //number of lines
        Line * pLines; //plines points to start and end
        char name[SIZE];
    };

    typedef struct {
        unsigned int numGraphicElements;
        GraphicElement * pElements; //the head points to pLines
    }
    VectorGraphic;

    void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * );
    void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic * );
    void CleanUpVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * );

    VectorGraphic Image;

    int main() {
        char response;
        InitVectorGraphic( & Image);

        _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

        while (RUNNING) {
            printf("\nPlease select an option:\n");
            printf("1. Add a Graphic Element\n");
            printf("2. List the Graphic Elements\n");
            printf("q. Quit\n");
            printf("CHOICE: ");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%c", & response);

            switch (response) {
                case '1':
                    AddGraphicElement( & Image);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    ReportVectorGraphic( & Image);
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    CleanUpVectorGraphic( & Image);
                    return 0;
                default:
                    printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    /*initialize the vectors, allocate memory*/
    void InitVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * pImage) { //addres of pImage is passed in
        pImage - > pElements = (GraphicElement * ) malloc(sizeof(GraphicElement)); //pImage is now the addess of image
        pImage - > numGraphicElements = 0;
    }



    /*add values into the vectors list.*/
    void AddGraphicElement(VectorGraphic * pImage) {
        struct GraphicElement * pElements;
        struct GraphicElement * pSecond;
        struct Point point;
        struct Line * line;
        unsigned int numLines;
        char name[256];
        int x;
        int y;
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;

        //allocate memory
        line = (struct Line * ) malloc(20 * sizeof(Line)); //allocate memory for line, in order to accsess Line struct values


     pElements = (GraphicElement * ) malloc(20 * sizeof(GraphicElement));
            printf("Please enter the name of the new GraphicElement(<256 characters): ");
            scanf("%s", name);
            strcpy(pElements - > name, name); //copy the elements name

            printf("How many lines are there in the  new GraphicElement? ");
            scanf("%u", & numLines);
            pElements - > numLines = numLines; //pass the number of lines indicated
            pImage - > pElements = pElements; //pass the number of lines indicated



        pImage - > pElements[pImage - > numGraphicElements] = * pElements;    //pass the elements into pImage
        pImage - > numGraphicElements++; //number of elements
```

Once I press q for quit. The program shows that I have a memory leak.
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->{69} normal block at 0x00EF9880, 264 bytes long.
Data: <> CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
Object dump complete

```
    /*clear everything, no memory leaks*/
    void CleanUpVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * pImage) {
        /* free all Lines pointers */
        for (int i = 0; i < pImage - > pElements - > numLines; i++) {
            free(pImage - > pElements[i].pLines);
        }
        pImage - > pElements - > numLines = 0;
        pImage - > numGraphicElements = 0;

        if (pImage != NULL) {
            free(pImage - > pElements);
        }
    }
```

Basically my program prompts the user for an element name, and amount of elements. After that I input int values for start(x,y) and end(x,y). After that I press q to quit and exit the program. I have stepped through the debugger without figuring out where this memory leak is. I have tried so many different strategies but I have failed. How can I free this memory leak?

Note: Also if I add a second element the memory leak duplicates.

Comment: The overarching answer is "don't user raw pointers unless you need them". Let data manage itself: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii

Comment: `- >` : Is it possible to compile?

Comment: @JimV yes it compiles and run, im using a c++ compiler in visual studios. Im slowly converting my code into c++ lol.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Lolz. clang puked right out of the gate on the `#include < stdio.h >`, as there is no file on my system called `" stdio.h "` (spaces relevant).

Comment: @WhozCraig its because I used an online indentation tool

Comment: Please abandon that online indentation tool immediately.  Never use it again on code that is to go anywhere near SO.  If that's the mess it makes, it simply isn't worth it.  It makes you look like a fool.

Comment: Why are you using raw pointers here? Overly complicated

Answer (score -1):

From the size of the of the memory block it looks like a pointer to a GraphicElement you try to free is not pointing to anything

Alway check raw pointers before using, dereferencing or freeing them:

```
void CleanUpVectorGraphic(VectorGraphic * pImage) {
    //always check input
    if(!pImage) {
         return;
    }
    /* free all Lines pointers */
    for (int i = 0; i < pImage->pElements->numLines; i++) {
        if(pImage->pElements && pImage->pElements[i] && pImage->pElements[i].pLines) {
            free(pImage->pElements[i].pLines);
        }
    }
    pImage->pElements->numLines = 0;
    pImage->numGraphicElements = 0;

    if (pImage != NULL) {
        free(pImage->pElements);
    }
}
```

Comment: Im getting non acceptable type conversion inside the if statement.